# Arrow function should not return assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

My code is working correctly in the app however, my eslint isn't liking it and is saying I should not return assignment. What is wrong with this?

```
<div ref={(el) => this.myCustomEl = el} />
```

Comment: add `{ }` around it

Comment: it's a warning, try `<div ref={(el) => (this.myCustomEl = el)} />`

Comment: Same warning. while it's a warning, I can't pass tests with the warning

Comment: `<div ref={(el) => { this.myCustomEl = e}l} />`

Comment: @epascarello typo with the e}l ?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**The Fix:**

```
<div ref={(el) => { this.myCustomEl = el }} />
```

**The Explanation:**

Your current code

```
<div ref={(el) => this.myCustomEl = el} />
```

is equivalent to:

```
<div ref={(el) => { return this.myCustomEl = el }} />
```

You are returning the result of this.myCustomEl = el. In your code, this is not really a problem -- however, one of the most frustrating bugs in programming occurs when you accidentally use an assignment (=) instead of a comparator (== or ===), for instance:

```
// This function will always return **true**, surprisingly
function isEqual(a, b) {
  // The warning would be thrown here, because you probably meant to type "a===b". The below function will always return true;
  return a=b;
}

let k=false;
let j=true;

if(isEqual(k,j)){
  // You'll be very, very, very confused as to why this code is reached because you literally just set k to be false and j to be true, so they should be different, right? Right?
  thisWillExecuteUnexpectedly();
}
```

In the above case, the compiler warning makes sense because `k=true` evaluates to true (as opposed to `k===true`, which is probably what you meant to type) and causes unintended behavior. Thus, eshint notices when you return an assignment, assumes that you meant to return a comparison, and lets you know that you should be careful.

In your case, you can solve this by simply not returning the result, which is done by adding enclosing brackets {} and no return statement:

```
<div ref={(el) => { this.myCustomEl = el }} />
```

You can also adjust the eshint warning like so:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign

Answer (score 9):

You're implicitly returning an assignment. `this.myCustomEl = el` is an assignment. You could fix this linting error by changing your arrow function to `(el) => { this.myCustomEl =el }` which is no longer implicitly returning because you wrapped it in `{}` instead of `()`.

*Side note*: Declaring an arrow function inline inside a render method will break a `PureComponent` because every time your component renders it has to declare a new anonymous function, so the shallow props comparison that a `PureComponent` does is broken by this and will always re-render.

Try making that a method of your component.

```
class MyClass extends React.PureComponent {
    getRef = (el) => { this.ref = el; }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.getRef} />;
    }
}
```

If the above syntax doesn't work for you, you can use the following:

```
class MyClass extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.ref = null;

        this.getRef = this.getRef.bind(this);
    }

    getRef(el) {
        this.ref = el;
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.getRef} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this errors w "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"

Comment: You can see it working in this [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvvk8vr2y).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to note something I came across. I have Prettier installed and it kept taking away my parens, resulting in eslint error:
To confirm this I added a prettier-ignore:

```
    <div>
        {/*prettier-ignore*/}
        <Map
            ref={(m) => {
                this.leafletMap = m;
            }}
            center={mapCenter}
            zoom={zoomLevel}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution={stamenTonerAttr}
                url={stamenTonerTiles}
            />
        </Map>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eslint will give us error message if we not applied flowe bracket

**Error:**

```
const isNumeric = n => return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
```

**Solution:**

```
const isNumeric = n => {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
    }
```